# Having a hard time with async vue router to vue fire

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vue-router

Im using vue fire as a plugin for connecting to firebase easily integrated with VUE JS and VUE router

im really having a hard time solving the null thing after manually binding

like this

line of code

```
bindUser() {
 this.$bindAsArray('buser',this.$firebaseRefs.busers.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(this.uid));
},
```

and route correctly

using this

```
toDashboard() {
    this.$router.push(`user/${this.buser[0].username}`)

},
```

why is it always a null? please help me here

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to manually `$bindAsArray`? Have you tried this on your component options?

```
firebase() {
    debugger // make sure $this.$firebaseRefs.busers... is what you expect
    return {
        buser: this.$firebaseRefs.busers.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(this.uid)
    }
}
```

Also are you using [Vue DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd)? That should help you inspect your bindings.